# warning in ./src/router/index.js export 'default' (imported as 'VueRouter') was not found in 'vue-router'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new to Vue and have been following the documentation to make on a basic Todo application. I am trying to create a register and login page and there seems to be something wrong with vue-router. There are several other warnings as well like, '"export 'inject' was not found in 'vue'".

[Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ht56.jpg)

I have tried many solutions of similar questions and problems but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
}).$mount('#app')
```

index.js (in ./router)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
 
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'signup',
    component: () => import('../components/Registration.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('../components/Login.vue')
  },
] 

export const router = createRouter({
    
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "todo",
  "author": "raj",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the list lf all warnings, that will really helpful to reproduce this issue locally

Comment: Hi @chans , Added an image link with the warnings. Please check.

Comment: You are using Vue 2 it seems, chekc for the vue router compatability for vue 2 also make changes to main.js and router js by replace this import "import * as Vue from 'vue'"

Comment: @chans This change removes one warning, export 'default' (imported as 'VueRouter') was not found in 'vue-router'. 
But other warnings still remain.

Comment: I beleive Vue Router 4.x is for Vue 3 only. With Vue 2 you need to use vue-router@3

Comment: So should i just uninstall vue-router 4 and install vue router3? @MichalLevý

Comment: Exactly. Also the API is little bit different (`new Router` instead of `createRouter()` etc) - check [the v3 docs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/)